# OneToOne mapping to an Entity from multiple owning entities

Tags: java, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I am a JPA newbie. I have what I believe is a very simple example, but I am having trouble implementing it. Basically, I have an entity that I want to "reuse" in other entities.

I have a `User` having two fields - `Home` and `Office`. Each of these in turn refers to an `Address`, like so:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Column 
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Home home;

    @OneToOne
    private Office office;

}

@Entity
public class Home extends Model {

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="home")
    private User user;

    // ...

}

@Entity
public class Office extends Model {

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "office")
    private User user;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Address extends Model {

    @Column
    private String line1;

    @Column 
    private String line2;

    @Column
    private String city;

    /*
     * Is this possible? Being owned by two entities?
     */


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")
    private Home home;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")
    private Office office;

    // ...
}
```

How do I achieve this?

---

### EDIT

I was originally running into this exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on example.Home.address references an unknown entity: example.Address
```

It turns out that one of the classes had imported the `@Entity` annotation from `org.hibernate` instead of from `javax.persistence`. After fixing this, the original exception went away ([this](http://techazizhk.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/orghibernateannotationexception-onetoone-or-manytoone-on-xxx-references-an-unknown-entity-xxx/#comment-75) helped me pin point the issue)

However, I now have a new exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: example.User.home -> example.Home
```

I don't quite understand this exactly. Should I call `save` the `Home` object before I do so on the `User` instance?

Comment: Everything looks right to me. What happens when you test this mapping?

Comment: I've been trying various things (including `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable`) and getting several exceptions. The latest (with the above code) is `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on example.Home.address references an unknown entity: example.Address`

Comment: That probably means that you forgot to list Address in the list of entities in your persistence.xml file.

Comment: There was a mismatch in the imports of the `@Entity` annotation. Edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` attribute to all the `@OnetoOne` annotations in all the entities.

Without this annotation, I would have to `save` each *owned* entity before saving the *owning* one. For example, I'd have to save a `Home` before saving the `User` that the home belongs to.

Adding the `cascade` attribute to the annotation takes care of this for you. You only need to save the `User` and the `Home` and `Address`es are automatically saved for you.

[This](http://www.reverttoconsole.com/blog/hibernate-jpa/understanding-orghibernatetransientobjectexception-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-before-flushing/) post helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make only 1 class User:

```
@Entity public class User extends Model   
      {        
         @Column      
         private String name;

         @Embedded
         @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "line1", column = @Column(name="column11")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "line2", column = @Column(name="column21")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name="column31"))
         })     
         private Address homeAddress;        

         @Embedded
         @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "line1", column = @Column(name="column12")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "line2", column = @Column(name="column22")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name="column32"))
         })
         private Address officeAddress;

         // .. setters, getters
      }    

      @Embeddable 
      public class Address extends Model   
      {   
          private String line1;       
          private String line2;       
          private String city;  
         // .. getters, setters  
   }
```

Comment: Ah, so I should have used ` @AttributeOverride` when I used `@Embedded`! I missed that and started getting exceptions about non-unique columns; which is why I launched into the mappings and `@OnetoOne`s .